# Applications not running correctly - with Custom Web Proxy enabled

Tags: c#, proxy, http-proxy

So I have built myself an Internet Proxy for work, aimed to block users from accessing bad websites.

It has been successful in that regard, however it does block some application use. Like you cannot search email history in outlook, and Teams does not connect.

I found by removing the "Secure" options for proxy settings eliminated the issue.

[image]

I did some googling but couldn't find what the difference between HTTP and Secure was specifically. At least in terms of how to handle the difference in my Proxy application.

---

The way my proxy works:

- All handled through sockets
- Listens through a socket over TCP
- Reads the request and determines weather to allow or not
- If allow, starts a relay by pointing the client socket and remote socket of the web request at each other to bounce traffic until all traffic has been processed.

This logic differs but is based of of the [MantalisProxy](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/)

Could anyone please advice what is "Secure" in proxy settings, what that means for configruing sockets in an application, and is it used by web browsers?

At the end of the day it was only ever meant to block users from browsing to bad websites, so if I just ignore this setting I would be happy witht hat. But I am still curious.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT #2**
I know understand that this setting means HTTPS. I realized the proxy stopped blocking HTTPS websites after I turned that one off.

So HTTPS works just fine in the browsers when turned on, and I can see the certificate etc. I wonder why not from an application?

Here is a slashed down version of the code logic, only showing the HTTPS aspect.

```
class Listener{
    OnReceive(){
        new Client(receivedSocket);
    }
}

class Client{
    socket clientS, remoteS;
    
    public Socket(Socket clientSocket){
        clientS = clientSocket;
    }
    
    void DoRequest(){
        string query = clientS... //Docode bytes received into request string
        var httpRequest = new httpRequest(query); //A class I made to break down the string, getting HTTP/HTTPS type, host header etc
        
        remoteS = new Socket(httpRequest.....); //Pass address port etc to new socket
        
        remoteS.BeginConnect(HostConnected());
    }
    
    void HostConnected(){
        if (httpRequest == HTTPS){
            clientS.BeginSend(query, OnSent());
        }
    }
    
    void OnSent(){
        if (clientSocket.EndSend(ar) != -1){
            StartRelay();
        }
    }
    
    void StartRelay()
    {
        // From here is is just redirecting traffic.
        // Information stored in two byte[], client and host.
        // When client reveices, send client buffer to host,
        // When host recives, send buffer to client
        // The on begin actions write and read from these byte[] buffers.
    }
}
```

Comment: Secure means https aka SSL traffic. Most likely, the proxy you have is presenting some certificate not trusted by your system and/or the applications you are running.

Comment: Hey @zaitsman. Thanks for your response, I worked this out just as I read your comment haha. Please see my edited post. Hoping you could shed some light. Theses sockets are of socket type Stream/TCP. Would this be making a difference? I have not seen anywhere before where an SSL certificate is attached to a socket, Im a bit confused.

Comment: Well based on the code you're trying to do ssl termination, which means that you need to implement a full SSL handshake if you want to work with this at TCP level, which is non-trivial.

Comment: Also, if SSL does work in the browser but not in `some` apps, then these apps might employ something called Certificate Pinning where they don't trust any cert but the one they know to be valid. There is no way to intercept that traffic unless you own those private keys or can modify the application code/data such that it also trusts the certs you do have.

Comment: @zaitsman, thanks heaps. Some good keywords/terminology to get my brain working! Researching has been hard since I started this, lots of irrelevant results. Do you think you could share a link on something that outlines what you mean by SSL handshake. As I have not seen anywhere using a socket that would require the passing of a cert.

Do you mean using a TCP client instead of a general socket? I have seen documentation on TCP listeners using certificates.

Comment: Practically you're trying to build this: https://www.telerik.com/fiddlercore 
The ssl handshake overview is everywhere in Google, e.g. here: https://medium.com/@kasunpdh/ssl-handshake-explained-4dabb87cdce

You can use wireshark/winpcap to capture the handshake in any browser session but trust me, implementing this correctly would be quite difficult.

Comment: Thanks @zaitsman. You are totally correct. I dug up the MentalistProxy that I was working of off, and realized just how much I ended up changing. Apparently not for the better haha.

I don't feel good about it. But I think Im going to just keep his code, and add a wrapper around the proxy code for my application. Im a junior developer, think Ill revisit in a few years when I learn more haha...

Again, thanks for your help.